# changing the Emmet's auto complete

Tags: emmet

I use sublime text as an editor for my html5 code, i also use Emmet to speed up my coding through Emmet's auto completion. In a blank .HTML file when i press control + space it generates the following code for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i just thought of it as generating some more code of my choice as i press control + space. 
I want it to generate this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width = device-width, intial-scale = 1.0">
    <link rel="" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <script src = ""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to change some configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own or edit existing Emmet snippets by editing the Emmet user settings file. You can open this file directly from Sublime Text (Sublime Text > Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings – User). By default it is empty and you need to add this structure:

```
{
  "snippets": {
    "html": {
      "abbreviations": {
        "mytrigger": "!!!+html>head+body"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

New snippets are defined within the `abbreviations` object. In this example the HTML will be generated by typing mytrigger and hitting `tab` in an HTML document. All abbreviations are online on [GitHub](https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/blob/master/lib/snippets.json).

Also there's an example on my [GitHub page](https://github.com/matuzo/sublime/blob/master/Emmet.sublime-settings).

Comment: Thank you for this! It would be nice if I could redfine an existing trigger though rather than come up with a new one.